# How to get mouse events in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

In a div, you can have onClick, onDragStart, onDragEnd mouse events.

How to get onDragEnd mouse events using JQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty common event.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  var $draggable = $('.draggable').draggabilly();
  $draggable.on( 'dragEnd', function() {
    console.log('dragEnd');
  });
});
```

You can check this website for reference:

https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/RNeGOQ